How can I unscrew valve cartridge from valve body?
I am trying to replace this cartridge and I cannot get the old one unscrewed. I've tried assorted tricks from YouTube videos with no luck. I soaked in vinegar overnight to remove corrosion, I also tried 3-in-1 oil and WD-40. I have vise grips I attached to the valve body a few different places and slipped the deep socket over the cartridge bolt but it just won't budge. Part of me wonders if there is something else that needs to be unscrewed first?
It's a Kohler "Forte" Widespread faucet.


What brand is the faucet? Specific model if you know it would be helpful too. Please [edit] that into your question.

Liz, please take the [tour]. You haven't resolved your previous question or credited helpful answers.

Heat causes cylindrical things to expand outward, which could loosen the connection for you. Dunk it in boiling water for a while, or gently heat the outer body with a torch or lighter until the whole thing just gets uncomfortably hot. Now put your Vice-Grip or slip-joint pliers above the nut and try turning the small nut counter-clockwise.

I don't know about this model, but be aware that some brands use opposite threads for cold and hot water, because they want the handles to rotate inward and outward (opposite directions) rather than both going clockwise and counterclockwise, and since that difference in direction is implemented in the cartridge they don't want you getting the cartridges mixed up.
I presume you have been assuming a normal right hand thread ("righty tighty, lefty loosy"); this one may go the other way. Try it, with appropriate caution not to apply so much force that you will damage it, and see if going "backwards" solves the problem.
If you can identify the manufacturer, you may be able to find documentation which will tell you whether this is the issue or not.
